# Script to delete lines from a file when the line starts with certain word

Tags: bash, awk, sed, dot

I have a dot file like below.

```
....
29 [label="OutRet", fillcolor="#90EE90", shape=box];
30 [label="In(alloced_return_alloca[bits 0 to ..])", fillcolor="#6495ED",
      shape=box];

subgraph cluster_Call4 { label="Call4 : f = (int *)alloca(sizeof(*f) * __lengthof_f);";
                           fillcolor="#B38B4D"; style="filled"; 17;16;
     };

edge [dir=back];
7 -> 6 [color="#000000", style="dotted"];
....
```

Whenever there is a subgraph attribute, I would like to remove that attribute. In some files there might be multiple sugraph attributes in which case I would like to remove all of them. I tried using `sed '/subgraph/ d' inputfile > outputFile` and `sed -i 's/subgraph.*//'` file outputFilebut it removes just the line which contains subgraph and gives a result like below:

```
30 [label="In(alloced_return_alloca[bits 0 to ..])", fillcolor="#6495ED",
      shape=box];

                           fillcolor="#B38B4D"; style="filled"; 17;16;
     };

  edge [dir=back];
```

Is there any way where I could remove the other two lines also(In general how many ever associated lines) i.e., the lines starting from subgraph till the occurance of "edge". Also, is there a way where we can output our result in the same file instead of writing it in another file?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I found out `sed '/subgraph/,/edge/d' inputFile` this does the work.

Answer (score 1):

To delete a sequence of lines delimited by some patterns, you should use an [address range](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/Range-Addresses.html#Range-Addresses) (two addresses separated by a comma `,`) with [regexp addresses](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/Regexp-Addresses.html#Regexp-Addresses) to select the lines between (including the first and the last), followed by a [delete](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/Common-Commands.html) command:

```
sed '/subgraph/,/edge/d' -i file
```

Use the `-i`/`--in-place` flag to edit the `file` in place (with an [optional backup](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/Command_002dLine-Options.html#Command_002dLine-Options)).

Btw, identical result is obtained by *inverting the logic* (with `!`) and printing out everything, except the lines in that range:

```
sed -n '/subgraph/,/edge/!p' -i file
```

Note we use `-n` to suppress automatic printing of pattern space, instead printing it explicitly with `p` command for each line *not* matched.